# Is it possible to make jQuery Masonry or Isotope maintain item's columns when an item's height changes?

Tags: jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm currently using Masonry to show a number of items, and each item has comments displayed in it's element. When you add a comment, the item's height grows, so I call `.masonry('reload')`. Depending on the item's position, sometimes the items below it maintain their column and just slide down, and other times they re-arrange to be in a new column.

Is there any way to make the items always stay in their initial column and only adjust the vertical position? If not with Masonry, then is this possible with Isotope or another library?

I'm not against writing a custom layout for isotope, but I'd rather not if a good solution is already available.